# Knights tour backtracking Lisp

Tags: lisp, backtracking, knights-tour

I am having some problems generating the correct output for this program. My output is almost correct, but missing of some steps. My code is as follows:

```
(defun kt (x y m n)                       ;set the board
  (setq totalmoves (* m n))     ;find the total moves
  (setq steps 1)                         ;count steps
  (setq lst (list (list x y)))  ;list visited with initial points
  (findPath x y totalmoves steps m n lst)       ;start tour with initial points
)

(defun findPath (x y totalMoves steps m n lst)
  (cond
  ((null lst) NIL)
  ((= steps totalMoves) lst)                ;if steps equals than total moves, then solution is complete
  ;try to solve the rest recursively
  ;1- down and right
  ((canMove (+ x 2) (+ y 1) m n lst)
    (findPath (+ x 2) (+ y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (+ x 2)        (+ y 1) lst))

)
;2- right and down
((canMove (+ x 1) (+ y 2) m n lst)
     (findPath (+ x 1) (+ y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (+ x 1) (+ y 2) lst))

)
;3- right ups
((canMove (- x 1) (+ y 2) m n lst)
     (findPath (- x 1) (+ y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList(- x 1) (+ y 2) lst))

)
;4- up and right
((canMove(- x 2) (+ y 1) m n lst)
     (findPath(- x 2) (+ y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList(- x 2) (+ y 1) lst))
)
;5 - up and left
((canMove(- x 2) (- y 1) m n lst)
     (findPath(- x 2) (- y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList(- x 2) (- y 1) lst))
)
;6- left and up 
((canMove(- x 1) (- y 2) m n lst)
     (findPath(- x 1) (- y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList(- x 1) (- y 2) lst))
)
;7- left and down
((canMove(+ x 1) (- y 2) m n lst)
     (findPath(+ x 1) (- y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList(+ x 1) (- y 2) lst))
)
;8- down and left
((canMove(+ x 2) (- y 1) m n lst)
     (findPath(+ x 2) (- y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList(+ x 2) (- y 1) lst))
)
(t 
 (findPath (car(car(reverse lst))) (car(cdr(car(reverse lst)))) totalMoves steps m n (reverse(cdr (reverse lst))))
  )
)
)

(defun appendList (x y lst)
  (setq lst (reverse(append (list (list x y)) (reverse lst))))
)

(defun check-visited (x y lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) 1)              ;if nth else to check in list
    ((equal (list x y) (car lst)) NIL)    ;check if curr is visited
    ((check-visited x y (cdr lst)))        ;recurse
  )
)

(defun canMove (x y m n lst)
  (if (and (<= 1 x)         ;for the correct state, all conditions below must be met          
       (<= x m)    ;height is more than or equal to x
       (<= 1 y)
       (<= y n)     ;width is more than or equal to y
       (equal (check-visited x y lst) 1)
  ) 
  1 NIL ;if all above conds are true, return true else return nil
)
)
```

The test code is

```
kt 1 1 5 5
```

The output is `((1 1) (3 2) (5 3) (4 5) (2 4) (1 2) (3 3) (5 4) (3 5) (1 4) (2 2) (4 3) (5 5) (3 4) (1 5) (2 3) (4 4) (2 5) (1 3) (2 1) (4 2))`

There is 21 steps listed here, but it is supposed to have 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect, since the function `findPath` does not try all the possible moves in a certain position, but, using `cond`, tries only the *first* possible move (in a `cond`, the first non `nil` branch is executed and the statement is terminated by returning the value corresponding `findPath` call). So, your function produces only the longest tour without backtracking, which is of exactly 21 moves.

In order to have the correct solution, you have to try *all* the possible moves, returning the first one that, through the recursive call to `findPath`, produces the right number of moves. In Common Lisp this can be done by using the `or` and `and` operators:

1. `or`, with *n* operands, returns the value of the first operand which is not `nil`, if exists, otherwise it returns `nil`: so if we arrange to put in a `or` all the recursive calls of `findPath`, if one of them returns the correct final value the `or` expression terminates returning that value;
2. `and` returns `nil` if any of its operands is `nil`, otherwise, if all of them are not `nil`, it returns the value of the last operand. So we can use it by first checking if a move is possible, and, if this is true, executing the move by calling `findPath` recursively. If the call returns `nil` then that move is not useful, otherwise we have found a correct tour.

Here is the new function:

```
(defun findPath (x y totalMoves steps m n lst)
  (if (= steps totalMoves)
      lst           ; if the steps are equal to total moves, then a solution is found
                    ; else try recursively all the possible moves from x y
                    ; 1- down and right
      (or (and (canMove (+ x 2) (+ y 1) m n lst)
               (findPath (+ x 2) (+ y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (+ x 2) (+ y 1) lst)))
                    ; 2- right and down
          (and (canMove (+ x 1) (+ y 2) m n lst)
               (findPath (+ x 1) (+ y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (+ x 1) (+ y 2) lst)))
                    ; 3- right ups
          (and (canMove (- x 1) (+ y 2) m n lst)
               (findPath (- x 1) (+ y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (- x 1) (+ y 2) lst)))
                    ; 4- up and right
          (and (canMove (- x 2) (+ y 1) m n lst)
               (findPath (- x 2) (+ y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (- x 2) (+ y 1) lst)))
                    ; 5 - up and left
          (and (canMove (- x 2) (- y 1) m n lst)
               (findPath (- x 2) (- y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (- x 2) (- y 1) lst)))
                    ; 6- left and up 
          (and (canMove (- x 1) (- y 2) m n lst)
               (findPath (- x 1) (- y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (- x 1) (- y 2) lst)))
                    ; 7- left and down
          (and (canMove (+ x 1) (- y 2) m n lst)
               (findPath (+ x 1) (- y 2) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (+ x 1) (- y 2) lst)))
                    ; 8- down and left
          (and (canMove (+ x 2) (- y 1) m n lst)
               (findPath (+ x 2) (- y 1) totalMoves (+ steps 1) m n (appendList (+ x 2) (- y 1) lst))))))
```

Finally, a few notes about the code.

*Don't use `setq` to initialize variables not previously declared*

`let` can be used to declare and initialize local variables, so that the function `kt` could be defined in this way:

```
(defun kt (x y m n)                            ; set the board
  (let ((totalmoves (* m n))                   ; find the total moves
        (steps 1)                              ; count steps
        (lst (list (list x y))))               ; list visited with initial points
    (findPath x y totalmoves steps m n lst)))  ; start tour with initial points
```

*Try to keep your code simple*

The function `appendList` is defined by appending a one-element list to the reverse of another, and the reversing the result. This is equivalent to simply append the first list to the second one, that is:

```
(defun appendList (x y lst)
  (append lst (list (list x y))))
```

*Use [generalized booleans](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_g.htm#generalized_boolean) to simplify conditions*

For instance, the function `check-visited` and `canMove` can be integrated in a single, more simple function:

```
(defun canMove (x y m n lst)
  (and (<= 1 x m)      ;for the correct state, all conditions below must be met          
       (<= 1 y n)
       (not (member (list x y) lst :test 'equal))))
```

*Try to factorize your code, or don't repeat similar code when not necessary*

The function `findPath` has a lot of repetitions, that could be eliminated with the use of the [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_a.htm) (`thereis` is the equivalent of the `or` in a `loop`):

```
(defun findPath (x y totalMoves steps m n lst)
  (if (= steps totalMoves)
      lst 
      (loop for (x-inc y-inc) in '((+2 +1) (+1 +2) (-1 +2) (-2 +1) (-2 -1) (-1 -2) (+1 -2) (+2 -1))
        for x1 = (+ x x-inc)
        for y1 = (+ y y-inc)
        thereis (and (canMove x1 y1 m n lst)
                     (findPath x1 y1 totalMoves (1+ steps) m n (appendList x1 y1 lst))))))
```

*Use conventions typical for the language in use*

In Common Lisp, camelCase is avoided, preferring to it the classical notation of names and verbs separated by dash, like `find-path` instead of `findPath`, or `can-move` instead of `canMove`, etc.